# 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase, command-line, firebase-tools

I tried to firebase log in my system.  i set environment variable and restart my computer but not working !

Any one to help me

first i  installed "npm install -g firebase-tools" then i command line "firebase login" entered.

same error show.

I attached my environment screenshot : [image]

This is command line error : [image]

---

To download and run the binary for the Firebase CLI, follow these steps:

1.Download the Firebase CLI binary for Windows.

2.Access the binary to open a shell where you can run the firebase command.

3.Continue to log in and test the CLI.

i try to direct this method firebase worked. but directory not set properly